# Differentiate between selenium Exception and other exceptions

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My test cases are in  selenium with c# language. I need to differentiate the failures that occurred due to Selenium Exceptions and other coding Exceptions in order to provide appropriate error message.

I an not sure if what i have tried below is correct. does Selenium.SeleniumException group all possible selenium Exceptions togeather. here is the catch block that I have tried:

```
    catch(Exception e)
    {
            if(e is Selenium.SeleniumException)
        {
            Console.Writeline("Defect in Application - Failed due to Selenium Exception");
        }
        else
        {
             Console.Writeline("Coding Error - Exception raised in code");
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is a bad idea. You'd be putting try catch around everything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

instead of trying to find out the exception type using `if-else` statements, use multiple `catch` statements. This enables you to act differently on different exception types.

Also, unless you know how to handle an exception, just let it propagate.

```
try
{
...
}
catch(WebDriverException exception)
{
    Console.Writeline("Defect in Application - Failed due to Selenium Exception");
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Console.Writeline("Coding Error - Exception raised in code");
}
```